# Swift 3 Oauth2 Imgur Refresh keys - error 400 "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"

Tags: swift, api, oauth, nsmutableurlrequest, imgur

I have an issue when calling the `/oauth2/token` endpoint of the Imgur API using Swift / `NSMutableURLRequest` and maybe it's actually just me setting up the request in a wrong way as I don't have a lot of experience with `NSMutableURLRequest`.
Scenario:
The user has already authenticated my App, he can post photos to his Imgur account.

Problem: 
Imgur requires to re-authenticate after 28 days.
That's why after authenticating the App you get a (temporary; for 28 days) `access_token` and a long-term `refresh_token` which you use after 28 days to get a new `access_token`.

I do following API call to retrieve a new `access_token` but always get the error:
`"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"` with error code `400`.

Here is my HTTP request:

```
if let reqUrl = URL(string: "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token?refresh_token=\(refreshKey)&client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)&client_secret=\(IMGUR_SECRET)&grant_type=refresh_token")
    {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: reqUrl)
        print("request: \(reqUrl)")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Client-ID \(CLIENT_ID)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
            if (error != nil){
                print("error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            print("response: \(response!)")
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("response string: \(responseString!)")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

`refreshKey`, `CLIENT_ID` and `IMGUR_SECRET` should all be correct.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I solved it this way:

```
let bodyString = "grant_type=refresh_token&client_secret=\(IMGUR_SECRET)&client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)&refresh_token=\(refreshKey)"

request.httpBody = bodyString.data(using: .utf8)
```

basically setting the parameters in the request's body instead of putting them in the URL.
Hope this can help someone else, too :)

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me after 3 hours of painful debugging _(:з」∠)_

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Thanks a ton. Wasted almost a day because of this. Really really appreciate it.